# Help with a vector inequality (Holder's / Jensen's)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, holder-inequality

Consider the non-negative vectors $c_i, a_i, b_i$, and positive constants $\alpha, \beta$ where $\alpha + \beta = 1$

Given that $c_i \leq a_i^\alpha b_i^\beta$. I can prove that $\sum_i c_i \leq \left(\sum_i a\right)^\alpha \left( \sum_i b_i\right)^\beta$ by Holder's inequality - i.e. it is a weakening of the given inequality.

How can I show the following?
$$
\frac{c_i}{\sum_i c_i} \geq \left(\frac{a_i}{\sum_i a_i}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{b_i}{\sum_i b_i}\right)^\beta
$$
I have checked it numerically, but I am having trouble proving it.
Intuitively, we are dividing one inequality by a "weaker" one, which switches the sign.
My guesses are to somehow use Holder's (or maybe Jensen's) inequality on the entire thing?

Attempt:

There exists $M,M_i\leq 1$ and $G\leq 1$ such that
$$c_i = M_i a_i^\alpha b_i^\beta$$
and
$$
 \sum_i c_i = M \sum_i a_i^\alpha b_i^\beta = M G \left(\sum_i a_i\right)^\alpha \left(\sum_ib_i\right)^\beta
$$
where the last has followed by Holder's.

Then the quotient is
$$
\frac{c_i}{\sum_i c_i} = \frac{M_i a_i^\alpha b_i^\beta}{M G \left(\sum_i a_i\right)^\alpha \left(\sum_ib_i\right)^\beta} 
$$

Hence it is left to prove $M_i \geq MG $ for all $i$.
For some $i$, $M_i \geq M$ already and hence the above inequality is already satisfied. So it is satisfactory to prove
$M_i \geq MG$ for those $M_i$ such that $M_i \leq M$...
Written another way,
$G \leq M_i/M \leq 1$ (i.e. proving the LHS).

This part seems quite unintuitive...
Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:

It might be helpful to note that the inequality is easily proven when $c_i = a_i^\alpha b_i^\beta$ (rather than less than). Divide both sides of this equality by Holder's inequality: $\sum_i c_i \leq \left(\sum_i a\right)^\alpha \left( \sum_i b_i\right)^\beta$ to obtain the desired result.

Perhaps from here there is some sort of continuity argument that can be used?

Comment: I tried $c = (0.5,0.9)$, $a=b=(1,1)$ and $\alpha=\beta=0.5$ and obtained:
$$
\frac{c_1}{\sum_{i=1}^2 c_i} = 0.3571
$$
and 
$$
\left(\frac{a_1}{\sum_i a_i}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{b_1}{\sum_i b_i}\right)^{1/2}=0.5
$$
thus the inequality does not follow. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FeedbackLooper the norm in the denominator for c should be the 1-norm.. does it still hold?

Comment: You mean I didn't used the correct expression, or that the inequality you want to prove has a different expression than in the question? Also, isn't the 1-norm of $c$ the same as $\sum_i c_i$ just as I used it, since $c_i\geq 0$

Comment: @FeedbackLooper My apologies! I think I read your comment as $c_i^2$... all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $a_i=b_i={1\over n}.$  Then $$\left(\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i =1}^n a_i}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{b_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}\right)^\beta={1\over n}.$$ Let $c_i={1\over ni}.$  Then $${c_1\over \sum_{i=1}^n c_i} < {1\over n}< {c_n\over \sum_{i=1}^n c_i}$$ Therefore the desired inequality is not satisfied for $n\ge 2.$

Comment: This looks correct, thanks. By any change could you think of possible additional hypotheses that would make this true? Not sure why I couldn't run across such a simple counterexample. Looks like the intuition of "dividing by a weaker inequality" has failed me!

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the answer, for   $a_i$ all equal and for $b_i$  all equal, the conclusion is satisfief only for $c_i.$ all equal. I do not see how to modify the hypothesis in a reasonable way.